# Dynamically load python modules

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have some python modules within a folder.

1. I want to read folder contents
2. Dynamically import each module
3. Dynamically load a method by the name of 'run()' within each imported module

How do I achieve this?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a good idea. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @PatrickCollins I would think the same if I saw this question. Too complex to explain, but in the context of my problem it's a good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)

```
import glob
module_files = glob.glob("*.py") #return a list of all names in folder ending '.py'
```

2)

```
modules = [__import__(module) for module in module_files]
```

3) I didn't understand the question properly, but I suppose, you should use gettattr: `gettattr(module, 'attribute')` is the same as `module.attribute`

`__import__` docstring says that it is prefered to use `importlib.import_module()` instead of it.

Comment: Will this work for packages that are in a folder inside the current folder?

Comment: @IanAuld of course you can use `glob.glob("folder_name/*.py")`. To get list of folders use `[name for name in glob.glob("*") if os.path.isdir(name)]` or `filter(os.path.isdir, glob.glob('*'))`